# Laravel 5.5 unique validation rule on seperate table with different column name

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have users and companies. A user belongs to one company.

I want to validate a user registration so that the `business_name` field they use to register is unique in the `companies` table, the goal is to not allow users from creating duplicate companies.

Here is my register function:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'business_name' => 'required|unique:companies',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->messages()], 401);
        }

}
```

The field I want to compare against is the `companies.name` to check for uniqueness.

Is this possible? At the moment it is trying to look for `business_name` in the `companies` table.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Never mind, managed to figure it out. Just needed an extra parameter to specify the column name:

```
'business_name' => 'required|unique:companies,name',
```